# Passing variable in classes/def and using commands in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, ttk

The following code (without showing it all) is my first attempt at using classes. I'm trying to mainly pass the variable box as I wish to retrieve the values from the Entry widgets in Tkinter.

I seem to have possibly made the class work but I'm having difficulties calling the definitions from inside by the 'command' in the Tkinter widgets.

If someone could explain where my badly written class code is going wrong and whether or not getting the box values is possible I would be very happy.

I apologise if this is a repeat of any previous questions.

```
class Start():
    def ChoiceBox(self, choice):


        column = 0
        if choice == "Fixed":
            choice_frame.grid_forget()      
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "No optimisation, value fixed.")
        elif choice == "List":
            i = [0, 1, 2, 3]

            for i in i:
                choice_title = Label(choice_frame, text='Value %g'% float(i+1), bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
                choice_title.grid(row=0, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

                self.box = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
                self.box.grid(row=1, column=column+i, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)

                tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Please fill in list values.")


        elif choice == "Interval" or "Optimisation":
            i = [0, 1]
            choice_title1 = Label(choice_frame, text='Min Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            choice_title1.grid(row=0, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            choice_title2 = Label(choice_frame, text='Max Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            choice_title2.grid(row=0, column=column+1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            for i in i:
                box = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
                box.grid(row=1, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
                tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Enter Min/Max values.")


    def StartBut(self):
    if self.box.get() == "":
            pass
        else:
            value = self.box.get()

list1 = OptionMenu(frame_table, variablelist, 'Fixed', 'List', 'Interval', 'Optimisation', command=Start.ChoiceBox)

but1 = Button(frame_but, text='Start', command=Start.StartBut)
```

UPDATE: Error I am now getting: 'unbound method 'ChoiceBox()' must be called with Start instance as first argument (got str instance instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def ChoiceBox(choice):` this should be `def ChoiceBox(self, choice)`:

read more about how python classes work [here.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I came to stackoverflow as I really struggle to understand any of the class tutorials I've found. I'm having trouble calling the definitions from the class later in the commands related to Tkinter.

Comment: @user2063 almost all GUI frameworks require basic knowledge of `Classes`, so probably you should a book or watch some online tutorial first to get your basics clear.

Comment: I know but for the task I've been given I don't have the time and simply need to clear this small point up. I'm eager to understand it as it annoys me to have to do this without really knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: Would you be able to help me organising my code into the class __init__ and such? I'd like to have a go at including the classes if that's what I need to do.